# Update an integer in an ADO RecordSet in C++

Tags: c++, ado, recordset

I am trying to update a record in an ADO RecordSet. The recordset is loaded from a XML file, that has previously been saved to disc via `rs->Save`.

When trying to assign an integer value, I get a _com_error Exception:

```
HRESULT = -2147217887
Description = Fehler bei einem aus mehreren Schritten bestehenden Vorgang. Prüfen Sie die einzelnen Statuswerte.
Message = IDispatch error #3105
Source = Microsoft Cursor Engine
```

The connections Error collection yields the same message and no additional details.

I cannot figure out why the assignment does not work. **What would be the correct way to assign the value to the field in question?**

The variant returned from the Recordset via `GetValue()` is of the type VT_I4.

It seems to be a conversion issue however. The field won't accept the type of variant it gets assigned. However `v = _variant_t(1l, VT_I4);` did not work either.

```
_RecordsetPtr DataService::LoadRecordsetFromXML(string fileName)
{
    //get a recordset
    _RecordsetPtr rs;
    try {
        HRESULT hr = rs.CreateInstance(__uuidof(Recordset));
        if(hr)
            return nullptr;

        hr = rs->Open(fileName.c_str(),"Provider=MSPersist;",adOpenDynamic,adLockBatchOptimistic,adCmdFile);
        if(hr)
            return nullptr;
        return rs;
    }
    catch (_com_error &ce)
    {
        ShowComErrorMessageBox(ce, rs);
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        AfxMessageBox("An unknown error has occured.");
    }
    return nullptr;
}

bool DataService::AddMemoToXML(Memo m, string fileName)
{
    _RecordsetPtr rs = LoadRecordsetFromXML(fileName);
    if(!rs)
    {
        return false;
    }
    std::stringstream fstream;
    fstream << "MEMO_ID = " << m.OldId;
    try {
        rs->Filter = fstream.str().c_str();
        HRESULT hr;
        if(rs->adoEOF)
        {
            hr = rs->AddNew();
        }
        //set values
        {
            FieldPtr field;
            _bstr_t bstring;
            _variant_t v;

            field = rs->Fields->GetItem("MEMO_ID");
            v = _variant_t(m.Id);
            DataTypeEnum t = field->GetType(); //adInteger
            field->PutValue(v); //Exception here
            field->Value = v; //Exception here
            field->Value = m.Id; //Exception here

            field = rs->Fields->GetItem("MEMO_TEXT");
            bstring = m.Text.c_str();
            field->Value = bstring; //works fine
        }
        rs->Update();
        rs->Filter = "";
        bool ret = SaveRecordsetToXML(rs, fileName);
        rs->Close();
        return ret;
    }
    catch (_com_error &ce)
    {
        ShowComErrorMessageBox(ce, rs);
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        AfxMessageBox("An unknown error has occured.");
    }
    return false;
}
```

*edit: The memo class for reference:

```
class Memo
{
public:
    Memo(void);
    virtual ~Memo(void);
    int Id;
    int OldId;
    wstring Text;
    int Person;
    wstring Firma;
    int OrgId;
    int JobId;
    wstring PCode;
    int UserId;
    int RolleId;
    wstring Kat;
    COleDateTime ContactDate;
    wstring Knoten;
    wstring CodeV;
    wstring CodeR;
    wstring Eint;
    wstring Stichwort;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Further testing on different fields yielded that the conversion like the following works.

```
field = rs->Fields->GetItem("PERSON");
v = 10l;
field->Value = v;
```

and that `v = _variant_t(1l, VT_I4);` is fine, too.

The error has to be related to the properties of the field MEMO_ID and is probably raised due to the fact, that it is an AutoId column.

An integer without a cast to long might use the wrong constructor of the variant, interpreting the number as memory location.